# Choosing Bluetooth Device/Dongle in Socket Code - Bluez Stack

Tags: linux, sockets, bluetooth, rfcomm

I have two dongles connected to my linux machine namely hci0 and hci1, i need to communicate with external bluetooth modules using socket communication. 
Is there any way where I can choose which device to use while establishing a socket connection? ( Eg hci0 or hci1, while starting the communication).

Reference Source :   [RFCommSocket](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html)

In this Example, all that's there is socket creation. I am able to do the communication and exchange data, but now i need to be able which device i want to start the communication from.

The Socket Creation is as follows in the example.

```
 s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);
```

Which doesn't allow me to choose which device I want to use, i know by default the system picks up the 1st device in the list, but is there a way to specify which device i could use?

My application needs 4 devices connected on dongle_a and 4 devices connected to dongle_b, is there a way to choose which device to start the socket connection on?

Answer (score 0):

```
// bind socket to port 1 of the first available 
// local bluetooth adapter
loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
loc_addr.rc_bdaddr = *BDADDR_ANY;
loc_addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr));
```

Bind to the appropriate `bdaddr` address instead of `BDADDR_ANY`.